# Return value from lambda "subscribe" in RxJava

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-room, rx-java2

I have this code:

```
private fun getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId: Int, taskId: Int): Int {
    compositeDisposable.add(
        viewModel.getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId, taskId)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                return it
            }
    )
}
```

However, the compiler shows me an error: 'return' is not allowed here

How can i return `it` value from this lambda?

My DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT isCompleted FROM Task WHERE chapterId = :chapterId AND taskId = :taskId")
abstract fun getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId: Int, taskId: Int): Flowable<Int>
```

My Repository Implementation:

```
override fun getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId: Int, taskId: Int): Flowable<Int> {
    return roomClientPlatform.courseDao().getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(
        chapterId, taskId
    ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
}
```

My ViewModel

```
fun getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId: Int, taskId: Int): Flowable<Int> {
    return repository.getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId, taskId)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer

--> You can't !

### Answer

You are trying to do synchronous job with an asynchronous one.

the scope `subscribe` is not the same as `getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId`. In `subscribe`you are doing an asynchronous task, waiting for data to be delivered.

#### First solution : Using blockingGet.

You can make subscribe synchrone by using the `.blockingGet()` method :

```kotlin
    private fun getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId: Int, taskId: Int): Int {
        compositeDisposable.add(
            viewModel.getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId(chapterId, taskId)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .blockingGet()
        )
    }
```

But this solution has a big downside : It might run on the UI thread and freeze the UI

### Second solution : Returning a Single.

For me, the best approach here, if you want to modify the view with the int, is to return a Single. The view will subscribe to it and you'll be able to use the int to modify the view.

Otherwise, if you want to use the int to do another call / operation, you can still return a single and use other operators like : zip, flatmap, merge, ... to combine it with another asynchronous call.

Comment: Can you show how to use Single in this example? I updated my code in question

Comment: If have some questions to fully understand what you want to do :

- Are you listening every changes on your database using getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId in DAO ? Or do you just want a data every time you call the method ?


- The method getTaskConditionByChapterIdAndTaskId who use a viewmodel is called in the view ?